# css navigation dropdown z-index issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, z-index

I am having issues with the dropdown showing on the following sites top navigation:

http://goo.gl/vIn0YN

I have tried adding z-index's in different places, but can't see the issue.

Works fine in Firewfox, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow: hidden; in your module-content class is the issue. it clips away everything outside the div container. 
remove it and it should work fine.